# How to Can I make my menu responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm creating my first blog to aside, but isn't responsive.
Anyone can help me to do become this small menu responsive? With my pc I see bad and also with other pc isn't good, if i zoom/rezoom it's a disaster. For the printer is many bad :D

Here the fiddle:

```css
main {
  margin: 1px;
}
aside.left {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 10%;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 2.5%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
aside.left > p {
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
aside.left > nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
aside.left > nav > ul > li {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20%;
}
aside.left > nav > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #444;
  padding: 10%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
aside.left > nav > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #444;
  background-color: #fff;
}
aside.left > p > img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #444;
}
aside.right {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  left: 170px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 100px;
  bottom: 310px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside class="left">
    <p>Mattew
      <img src="http://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/456/45610.png" alt="avatar">
    </p>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="1#2">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2#2">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="3#2">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <aside class="right">
    <article>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nam a non numquam, architecto doloribus nulla voluptatum vel possimus facilis odio laudantium quod aut dolorum, obcaecati cupiditate explicabo. Eum, magnam!
    </article>
  </aside>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `min-width` to the container of menu, and adding `left: 0;` will also help to stick the menu on left but it depends on you.

Try this:

```
aside.left {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 10%;
  width: 15%;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 2.5%;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypzkdme1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the help :D